# Which one to install first when dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: dual-boot

I want to make Ubuntu and Windows Dual Boot.Now which one I should install first?

Answer (score 2):

Install windows first

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

' A Windows OS should be installed first, because its bootloader is very particular and the installer tends to overwrite the entire hard drive, wiping out any data stored on it.'